# Trying svn propedit svn:ignore gives me svn: E205007

Tags: svn, ignore

I'm trying to ignore some data in svn by running the following command

```
svn propedit svn:ignore <somefolder>
```

but it gives me

```
svn: E205007: None of the environment variables SVN_EDITOR, VISUAL or EDITOR are set, and no 'editor-cmd' run-time configuration option was found
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`svn` needs to know which editor to start to allow you to edit the directory properties.  You would probably also get a similar error if you tried to do `svn ci` without passing the log messages as a command argument.

On Unix-like systems it is traditional to use environment variables named `VISUAL` or `EDITOR` to specify the path to your preferred editor. `VISUAL` would usually be a full-screen editor, like `vi` or `emacs`, while `EDITOR` might be TTY-style editor, like `ed`. In your case, you might want to try something like:

```
setenv VISUAL /usr/bin/vim
```

(or if you prefer a different editor, use that).

These environment variables are usually defined in your shell's startup files, so that
would be the place to put the `setenv` command so the variable will be available in future sessions.

Comment: Perfect, thanks! Added export `export VISUAL=vim` and `export EDITOR=$VISUAL` to my `~/.bash_profile` and now everything works fine.